# How to obtain posted string from iPhone app on Server Side

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, xml, web-services

I'm new to Web Services for iPhone and have a quick question. I want to send some values up to my php script on the server, however since there are so many values I dont want to include them in the actual URL (access them in $_GET in PHP). I want to send up a XML string that will allow my PHP script to get all the data and process it. So far I have the following template for sending data:

```
NSURL *someURL = ...
NSString *xmlString = @"This would be the entire XML message";
NSData *data = [xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:someURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:90];

[req setHTTPBody:data];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Now my understanding is this would submit the XML to the PHP script. My question is how would I obtain this on the server side ... what would the $_POST['?????'] value be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read:

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
```

or do:

```
$rawPost = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

From the manual:

> php://input allows you to read raw
>   data from the request body. In case of
>   POST requests, it preferrable to
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives.
>   Moreover, for those cases where
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated
>   by default, it is a potentially less
>   memory intensive alternative to
>   activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data.
>   php://input is not available with
>   enctype="multipart/form-data".

For more information, check out:

http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Comment: Thanks webbiedev, so am I right in assuming echo $rawPost; would echo out the XML that was posted by the Obj-C code (from the example provided)? Sorry, I can't test this as I wont have access to my mac until the weekend, but would like to clearify so I can hit the deck running, so to speak :)

Comment: It is raw so it will be encoded. Pass `$rawPost` to `urldecode()` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `print_r($_REQUEST)` to see all GET/POST variables.

Since you're calling the page directly, I'd probably setup a quick script to log the data to a file when the page is called.